# When audio finished, show play button again?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a real nooby haha and can't figure this out on my own.

When I load the page, it shows the play button. I hit play (music starts playing) and the pause button is showing for whenever I like to pause the music.

But when the music is finished playing it keeps showing me the pause button.

Question; how can I get the play button back whenever the music is finished playing?

```js
var audio, playbtn, mutebtn, seek_bar;
function initAudioPlayer(){
 audio = new Audio();
 audio.src = "./audio/D.mp3";
 audio.loop = false;
 // Set object references
 playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
 // Add Event Handling
 playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);
 // Functions
 function playPause(){
  if(audio.paused){
      audio.play();
      playbtn.style.background = "url(./images/pause.png) no-repeat";
     } else {
      audio.pause();
      playbtn.style.background = "url(./images/play.png) no-repeat";
     }
 }
}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

```html
 <button id="playpausebtn"></button>
```

Comment: Did you look at documentation for the audio events? Seems like first thing I would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an event listener for `ended` event and run the logic you want inside that.

> The **ended** event is fired when playback or streaming has stopped
>   because the end of the media was reached or because no further data is
>   available.

More info about this event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended).

```
audio.addEventListener("ended", function(){
     // show play button
});
```

Comment: Just complementing, you can check all events at the left sidebar [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)